# Addline is not available in skpath in skiasharp

Tags: asp.net-core, skiasharp

In core platform ,i am using SKPATH instead of GRAPHICSPATH(SYSTEM.DRAWING) but i cant add the line in the SKPATH.`

```
Path.AddLine(x,y) //Addline is showing error where path refers to the SKPATH
```

Is there any other alternative solution for adding the line in the SKPATH.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

SkiaSharp sometimes uses a few different terms. What you want is probably:

```cs
var path = new SKPath();

// start the path somewhere
path.MoveTo(0, 0);

// draw a line from (0,0) to (10,0)
path.LineTo(10, 0);

// draw another line from (10,0) to (10,10)
path.LineTo(10,10);
```

There are a few other members, but they basically follow a pattern of `AddXXX` for closed shapes (eg `AddRect`, `AddOval`), and `XXXTo` for line segments (eg `LineTo`, `ArcTo`).